# Получение индекса активной сцены в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Добрый вечер!

Необходимо занести индекс активной сцены в переменную `i`.
Следующий вариант кода выдаёт ошибку.

```
using ...
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

byte i;
i = (byte)(SceneManager.sceneLoaded());
```

Как корректно реализовать поставленную задачу (используя SceneManager)?

Comment: `SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex`

Comment: Правда, не работает, если сцена из AssetBundle загружена.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Нужно вот это:

```
SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
```

Т.к. `GetActiveScene()` возвращает текущий активный на данный момент объект  **[Scene](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene.html)**, то вот в нем как раз есть тот самый заветный индекс - **[Scene.buildIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.Scene-buildIndex.html)**. И `name` тоже, если вдруг понадобится.